# Will env. vars affect imports from node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm extracting some utility functions from my project into `npm modules` so I can use them in other projects.

Some of these functions rely on `API Keys`, and use different `API Keys` for `DEV` and `PROD` environments.

In the main project, this isn't a problem, as my `build` process sets the `environment vars` correctly, and my `webpack build` process results in the correct `keys` in the source code.

If I include the `API Keys` in the `npm modules` with the same `DEV | PROD` ternaries, will the `environment vars` of the main project work the same for the modules as they did for the code when it was in the main project?

```
// mymodule/index.js
export default function() {
  return __PROD__ === true ? "abc" : "123"
  // ....
}

// project/index.js in __DEV__ environment
import getKey from 'my-module'

getKey() // should return "123"
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but what you're using aren't environment variables. They're probably variables you're filling in with Webpack's `DefinePlugin`, such as

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __PROD__: true
})
```

When Webpack compiles your code, the plugin automatically replaces these magic global variables with the value in the configuration file.

The correct way to use an environment variable in node is `process.env`, as in `process.env.__PROD__`, and run your program with something like `__PROD__=true node index.js`, or by the more common convention `NODE_ENV=production node index.js`.

If you're publishing the compiled Webpack code to npm, then it should work with whatever `DefinePlugin` value you've set for the npm compile Webpack configuration.